# How to capture high quality snapshot image of Sprite Kit SKView?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I followed the traditional way of drawing the view into UIImage :

```
  UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(controller.skView.bounds.size, NO, 1.0);
[controller.skView drawViewHierarchyInRect:controller.skView.bounds afterScreenUpdates:YES];
UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

I have tried to set the third parameter in `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions` to 2.0 or larger,however the quality of the Image doesn't get better.

Here I post two images(1st is captured by the code,2nd is captured by pressing Home + power button ,this function is supported by system).

[image]
[image]

I want to know if there  is a way to make it better.Appreciating any help!

Comment: UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(controller.skView.bounds.size, <-- maybe you need to consider converting from points to pixels on Retina devices here? Ie on Retina size is 2x what skView.bounds.size is.

Comment: It doesn't works,sadly.@LearnCocos2D

Comment: Well it should @AndrewCarl

Comment: @LearnCocos2D  Yes , try again and you are right!